# How to load an DLL based on the Version?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I am using an external library whose DLL versions are from v2014 to v2020. 
Issue is i am currently linking v2020  DLL in my application. if i load any lower version file it will show an warning message and it will upgrade that to new version format, but the conversion time is more if the size of that file big.

I know which version of file i am importing based on it i need to load that particular version DLL.

i need an approach to achieve this. i have seen some examples on boost interprocess communication , #loadLibrary approach.

Comment: If the external DLL is properly built, and has a valid `VERSION` resource, you can use `GetFileVersionInfo` (and related API calls) to check that version information before loading the file. I can provide some guidance and sample code, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: I have multiple DLLs in a single folder each belongs to different versions.  So if i have 10 versions, each version will have a folder of multiple dlls. My exe will be built with latest version of dlls.
The problem here is When I Load a lower version file, It should run through all the available versions and return me a pointer which can be used in my current exe.
Q1: How to replace my current version dlls with a lower version dlls.
Q2: Lets suppose that each version has an exe, from my current exe, if i trigger the required version exe,then how can i be able to access the pointer returned.

Answer (score 0):

You do that naming library direct with version or versioning your code inside library.